# Expression to calculate sum in QGIS Attribute table

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, attribute-table, expression, summarizing

There is a shapefile about facilities with columns `"country"` and `"annual production"`.

I am looking for an expression for a calc field to summarize total production for ***all countries***.

For example: if a country has 5 facilities, I need to sum up each facility for the total production of this country.

Is there some expression to do that?

[image]

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To calculate the sum per country, use this expression:

```
sum("production", group_by:="country")
```

Replace `"production"` and `"country"` with the field names you have.

Comment: Thanks, it works, but "country" does not need to replace, it must stay like in Your example.

Comment: Yeah, as long as you use the same names, they can stay like this in the expression, of course

Answer (score 0):

Try the Sum function:

```
 sum("annual production","country")
```

I feel this should also work with the aggregate function:

```
 aggregate('[[your layer name]]',sum,"annual production","country"=@parent)
```

Comment: I think there are some errors in the second expression, take a look to the [`aggregate`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#aggregate) documentation. The correct expression is. `aggregate('[[your layer name]]', 'sum', "annual production", "country"=attribute(@parent, 'country'))`

Comment: To Hjall: no, doesn't work.